# How to break r.js build in case of any javascript syntax errors?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, uglifyjs, r.js

I am using r.js(2.1.16) and UglifyJS2 and I want to break the build if a file has  **Duplicate data property in object literal** or any javascript syntax error.

Now when I run r.js build with above mentioned errors; build is successful but while running application I am facing issues because of javascript syntax errors.

I have removed following try-catch block in r.js(line number: 24501) file and build started breaking (which is my requirement),

```
//            try {
                astRoot = esprima.parse(contents, {
                    loc: true
                });
//            } catch (e) {
//                logger.trace('toTransport skipping ' + path + ': ' +
//                             e.toString());
//                return contents;
//            }
```

Is there any configuration in r.js or UglifyJS2 by which the build can fail in such cases?

Answer (score 1):

James Burke (the author of RequireJS) [commented](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/866#issuecomment-157145161) in a bug report that:

> There is no option for this in the optimizer, it is best to run a linting pass before doing the build, as a step outside of the r.js optimization step.